# pyparsing how to create grammar object from string

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am having grammar for my pyparsing application in DB. They are in String format. I want to convert the same to the grammer object in my application and struck up with it.

```
Word(alphas) + Word(nums)
```

Above snippet is one of the entries in the database for which i need to construct grammer object

Can any one let me know how it can be accomplished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the eval or exec. For Example:

```
g = eval("Word(alphas) + Word(nums)")
```

Comment: But it can be unsafe, if in a database will be a malicious code

Answer (score 2):

For something safer than eval, you can use the EBNF parser that is included with the pyparsing source installation, or [download it from the wiki](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/ebnf.py).  Then you can define your parser using EBNF, generate a pyparsing parser, and use that to parse the related text.